# What kind of Groovy object is Jenkins "env"?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

In Jenkins pipelines, if I assign any key-value to env, I can access it like normal variables in string interpolation and environment variables in shell script. How does this work?

I see the probable implementation [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/cps/EnvActionImpl.java#L169) but can't figure out how it works.

[Update]

In below code snippet, I can access the env properties without accessor -->

```
node {
   stage('Preparation') {
        env.foo = "bar"
        echo "foo is $foo"
   }
}
```

Comment: The type you are referring to is a `Map`.

Comment: How am I able to access this map property inside a GString without specifying the object accessor? I'll add a code snippet to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't delved into the Jenkins code, but you could implement something like this by implementing the [`propertyMissing()`](https://groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html#_propertymissing) method in a class, which would write to the script binding. The `propertyMissing` method gets called when the code is trying to access a property that is not declared in the class.

```groovy
class MyEnv {
    groovy.lang.Script script

    MyEnv( groovy.lang.Script script ) {
        this.script = script
    }

    def propertyMissing( String name ) {
        script.getProperty( name )
    }    
    def propertyMissing( String name, value ) {
        script.setProperty( name, value )
    }    
} 

def env = new MyEnv( this )  // pass the script context to the class

env.foo = 42                 // actually assigns to the script binding

println "env.foo: $env.foo"  // prints 42
println "foo: $foo"          // prints 42

// It also works the other way around...
foo = 21                     // assign to the script binding (Note: "def foo" would not work!)
println "env.foo: $env.foo"  // prints 21
```